# Evaluating integral (Three Dimensional Delta Function)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I am trying to evaluate the following integral (3-d delta function):

$$\int (10x^2 +3y^3-4z^2+8)\delta(2\vec{r})d^3\vec{r}$$

---

Not sure where to proceed, I know that $$\delta^3(\vec{r}) = \delta(x)\delta(y)\delta(z)$$

$$\delta(\alpha x) = \frac{1}{|\alpha|^n}\delta(x)$$

$$\begin{equation}
\delta^3(\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0)=\delta(x-x_0)\,\delta(y-y_0)\,\delta(z-z_0)
\end{equation} \implies \int\delta(2x)dx\int\delta(2y)dy\int\delta(2z)dz $$ $$= \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{8}$$

but then substituting in the function $(10x^2 +3y^3-4z^2+8)$ will the answer then be $1$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is $1$ because of another delta property:

$$\delta(\alpha x) = \frac{1}{|\alpha|^n}\delta(x)$$

for a $\delta$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Ty, in order to completely write down the answer will my above evaluation be correct steps?